# React testing library fails test when all tests run togother but get success when run individually

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

i have created a simple app using create react app as follows. there are 2 test conditions first test confirms the element exists as the localStorage data exists. second test confirms the element is not there as there is no localStorage data

when i run both test together second test fails. but when i run the failed test individually it get success.

it seems the render in first test leaks into next test. how can i fix this.

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  console.log(localStorage.token,"ssdd")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {localStorage.getItem('token') && <div data-testid={"hello"}>hello</div>}
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.test.js

```
import {cleanup, render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

describe('App', function () {
  afterEach(cleanup)
  it('should render hello', function () {
    localStorage.token = "dfdfdf"
    const {queryByTestId,unmount} = render(<App/>)
    expect(queryByTestId('hello')).toBeInTheDocument()
    unmount()
  });
  it('should not render hello', function () {
    const {queryByTestId} = render(<App/>)
    expect(queryByTestId('hello')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the `'token'` item in `localStorage` at the end of the test case.

`App.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  console.log(localStorage.token);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">{localStorage.getItem('token') && <div data-testid="hello">hello</div>}</header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`App.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import App from './App';

describe('App', function () {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  it('should render hello', function () {
    localStorage.token = 'dfdfdf';
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<App />);
    expect(queryByTestId('hello')).toBeInTheDocument();
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  });
  it('should not render hello', function () {
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<App />);
    expect(queryByTestId('hello')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71498108/App.test.jsx (8.85 s)
  App
    ✓ should render hello (41 ms)
    ✓ should not render hello (4 ms)

  console.log
    dfdfdf

      at App (stackoverflow/71498108/App.jsx:4:11)

  console.log
    undefined

      at App (stackoverflow/71498108/App.jsx:4:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.629 s, estimated 10 s
```